# How to link data records in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file which I can read into a pandas data frame. The data is like:

```
+--------+---------+------+----------------+
|  Name  | Address |  ID  |   Linked_To    |
+--------+---------+------+----------------+
| Name 1 | ABC     | 1233 | 1234;1235      |
| Name 2 | DEF     | 1234 | 1233;1236;1237 |
| Name 3 | GHI     | 1235 | 1234;1233;2589 |
+--------+---------+------+----------------+
```

How do I run analysis on the linkage between ID and the Linked_To columns. For example, should I be turning the Linked_To values into a list and doing a VLOOKUP type analysis on the ID column? I know there must be an obvious way to do this but I am stumped.

Ideally the end result should be a list or dictionary which has the entire attributes of the row, including all of the other records its linked to.

OR is this a problem where I should be transforming the data into an SQL database?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? The data is delimited by tabs.

Comment: Are the IDs unique?

Comment: Yes the IDs are unique, no duplicates under the ID column.

Comment: @OwaisArshad if you are working with pandas dataframe, we could try pandas' way for this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47687031/7964527

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for the unique and non-unique cases, a dictionary of IDs in linked_to for each ID could be obtained via:

```
def linked_ids(df):
    #set up the dictionary
    dict = {}
    #iterate through the rows
    for row in df.index:
        #separate the semi-colon delimited linked to field
        linked_to = df.ix[row,'Linked_to'].split(";")

        if df.ix[row,'ID'] not in dict.keys():
            dict[df.ix[row,'ID']] = []

            for linked_id in linked_to:
                if linked_id not in dict[df.ix[row,'ID']]:
                    dict[df.ix[row,'ID']].append(linked_id)
        else:
            for linked_id in linked_to:
                if linked_id not in dict[df.ix[row,'ID']]:
                    dict[df.ix[row,'ID']].append(linked_id)

    return dict
```

Comment: No worries mate :)

Answer (score 2):

If you working with pandas dataframe , try this

```
df.set_index('ID').Linked_To.str.split(';').to_dict()
Out[142]: 
{1233: ['1234', '1235'],
 1234: ['1233', '1236', '1237'],
 1235: ['1234', '1233', '2589']}
```

Comment: Thanks!This worked as well. I changed it slightly to: df.set_index('ID')['LINKED_TO'].str.split(';').to_dict()

Comment: @OwaisArshad aha :-)